# Execute selenium library in Python + webdriver and blocked session

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I'm using a process that uses the selenium library and webdriver.
How can I avoid blocking the screen while the script is running? Because when the session is blocked, the process is interrupted.
I'm using a mac.

Answer (score 0):

With

```
# disable sleep (while plugged in or on battery)
cmd='pmset -a disablesleep 1' 

and at the end of the code
#re-enable sleep
cmd='pmset -a disablesleep 0'
```